# How to predict behaviour based on weka clustering

Tags: machine-learning, weka, correlation, collaborative-filtering

I have executed a hierarchical cluster on data which is in following format :

```
userid keyword
1  test
2  tester
3  test
4  thisisatest
5  user
```

There are thousands of entries in this format and when I use the visualizer here is the output :

[image]

How do I interpret this graph ?  Can I combine this hierarchical cluster and use collaborative filtering to predict what other keywords user may use ?